# Update MySQL Issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, xampp, liferay

[image]

Hello, I have the following issue. I am trying to start liferay tomcat bundle.Everything is OK, but an error appears which says " Please upgrade to at least MySQL 5.6.4. The portal no longer supports older versions of MySQL." I have tried reinstalling XAMPP Server with the latest version,but didn't work. Any suggestions how to update Mysql 5.5 to at least 5.6

Comment: MySQL 5.6+ for Liferay 7+ is necessary.

Comment: Yes, but I can't update MySQL version to 5.6

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Also - note that Stackoverflow is about programming issues, not configuration or installation of existing software (see [help/on-topic]). There are other sites in the stackexchange network where upgrades to mysql are on topic - that's completely independent of Liferay (but you'd be welcome in the Liferay community too, on https://liferay.dev/)